# Display TimeSpan correctly in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a TimeSpan value of `00:02:02.0`  basically 0 hours 2 minutes 2 seconds and 2 milliseconds.

I will always have 0 hours.  How do you format ssrs to read 2.02.0?  I know you can do =Fields!FinishTime.Value.ToString("mm:ss:fff") however it always produces #error as value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are pretty close, `ToString()` is correct since SSRS doesn't know how to work with TimeSpans, but you'll need to wrap a `Format` around it to use the format string and convert it back to a date to use the date formatting patterns:

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!FinishTime.Value.ToString()), "mm:ss:fff")
```

**EDIT**:

If your dataset contains NULLs, you won't be able to use a simple `IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FinishTime.Value), Nothing, <format formula>)` because [IIF does not short-circuit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) and you'll see an #error when it tries to use the ToString() function on NULLs.  So instead try some custom code ([retrieved from an MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3042602f-1e44-43ae-8b5b-22da1a14c67c/sql-reporting-services-time-formatting?forum=sqlreportingservices)):

```
Function FormatTimeSpan(TS as TimeSpan) as String
Dim DT as new DateTime(TS.Ticks)
Return DT.ToString("mm:ss:fff")
End Function
```

And call it like this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FinishTime.Value), Nothing, Code.FormatTimeSpan(Fields!FinishTime.Value))
```

Comment: Nice!  How do you handle when the time is messed up?  it shows #error for like 2 out of the 70 results

Comment: I tried =IIF(Len(Fields!FinishTime.Value) > 1,"",Format(CDate(Fields!FinishTime.Value.ToString()), "mm:ss:f")) but i still get error

Comment: Depends what the 2 results are returning to give you the #error. I imagine a NULL would still cause problems, so you could use `IsNothing()` to check for that, but it may be easiest to check what the query is returning for those rows.

Comment: stu- it is null, but I have to return those rows, Isnothing still produces #Error

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to do this, assuming you are using a SQL Server data source.  In your SQL statement use this where you select the FinishTime field:

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, TableName.FinishTime) AS FinishTime, ...
```

It handles nulls just fine, and you can use the built-in formatting options in SSRS to format it.