# SSRS time shown as HH hours MM minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on an SSRS report and would like to display a length (time) field as HH hours MM minutes e.g. **2 hours 10 minutes** rather than my current output **02:10:00**

Currently I am achieving this in the SQL query (where start and end are datetime fields):

```
    CAST((end - start) as time(0))
```

I am happy to change the SQL if required but ideally would like to make the change to the SSRS report if possible.

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display TimeSpan correctly in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170189/display-timespan-correctly-in-ssrs)

Comment: Get the datediff in minutes.  Extract the hours part.  Concatenate ' hours ' afterwards.  Get the remaining minutes.  Concatenate ' minutes.' afterwards.

Comment: As a note, in ToString, you can use a custom format (`hh hours mm minutes`) or similar

Comment: Thanks I used the Custom Format and ToString function and it worked perfectly! Many thanks for your help, I had spent a long time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Leave your `datetime` comparison as a `datetime` value and then in your SSRS report, use the `format` function to specify how your time should be displayed.  You can use a backslash to escape any key letters:

```
=format(Fields!TimeFieldName.Value, "hh \hour\s mm \minu\te\s")
```